# SVG defintions and "use" produce overlapping graphics

Tags: html, svg, icons

The definitions look like this:

```
<svg style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path ...
    </symbol>     
    <symbol id="icon-2" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path ...
    </symbol>
    ...
</svg>
```

and they are used like this:

```
<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-2" /></svg>
```

The icons are shown but all of them at once, overlapped. I thought it's because they have the same viewBox, so I changed the y coordinate for each icon like this:

```
0  0 32 32
0 32 32 32
0 64 32 32
...
```

But then no icon shows up. Am I missing something?

Comment: if you use only 1 svg container for placing your symbols (not declaring), change the `y` coordinate of their `use` element so they don't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. I can't see anything wrong with this approach. The following example works just fine:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="icon-1" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <circle cx="16" cy="16" r="12" fill="#f00" />
    </symbol>     
    <symbol id="icon-2" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
      <path d="m4 4h24v24h-24v-24z" fill="#00f" />
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-1" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
  <use xlink:href="#icon-2" />
</svg>
```